# How can I convert a GAIA-magnitude "G" to Johnson "V"?

Tags: magnitude, gaia

**Question:** How can I convert the Gaia-magnitude *G* (and *G_ESTIMATE*) into a *V*-magnitude? The solution probably can be found in the Gaia Data Release Documentation for Gaia's EDR3 ("Early Data Release 3"), specifically section 5.5.1, [Relationships with other photometric systems](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GEDR3/Data_processing/chap_cu5pho/cu5pho_sec_photSystem/cu5pho_ssec_photRelations.html), but I have to admit, that I can't make heads or tails of it.

**Related Question:** The question *[Relationships between G magnitude, Johnson V magnitude, and spectral type of stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44670/relationships-between-g-magnitude-johnson-v-magnitude-and-spectral-type-of-sta)* is related in that it wants to explore the relationship between *G* and Johnson-*V*. However, my separate question is not a "duplicate", because the other question has the relation between the magnitudes and spectral type as its focus (perhaps erroneously, shouldn't the relation be between a colour index and spectral type?).

**Background:** I am exploring the solar neighbourhood based on the paper *The 10 parsec sample in the Gaia era* (see the [CDS](https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/J/A+A/650/A201)-entry). Among other things I want to know the objects' respective brightnesses and what is visible to the naked eye (or a specific instrument). For this I want to use the "V"-filter (column "V" in the catalogue to the paper). A bit more than 50% of the non-planetary objects in the catalogue have a V-mag listed. Most of the remaining non-planetary objects (stars, low-mass stars, white dwarfs, brown dwarfs) have either a Gaia-magnitude *G* or an estimated Gaia-magnitude *G_ESTIMATE*. Therefore I need a way to convert *G* to *V*. The conversion probably not straight-forward since $G$ is a band covering wavelengths 330–1050 nm, and $V$ seems to cover only 470-700 nm.

**Looking for:** I need an equation I can use in a spreadsheet program to convert *G*/*G_ESTIMATE* to *V*. Is there one, or does conversion require more information than is given in the 10 parsec-catalog?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function that converts $G$ to $V$ because the conversion depends on stellar temperature/colour.

For Gaia EDR3 data the most useful transform for you is
$$G-V=-0.02704 +0.01424(G_{bp}-G_{rp})-0.2156(G_{bp}-G_{rp})^2 + 0.01426(G_{bp}-G_{rp})^3 $$
from [Table 5.7](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GEDR3/Data_processing/chap_cu5pho/cu5pho_sec_photSystem/cu5pho_ssec_photRelations.html) of the EDR3 data guide.

Most sources with $G$ data will also have a $G_{bp}-G_{rp}$ colour.

Note that the DR2 and EDR3 photometric systems are slightly different.

For Gaia DR3 the transform is the same as for EDR3, from [Table 5.9](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GDR3/Data_processing/chap_cu5pho/cu5pho_sec_photSystem/cu5pho_ssec_photRelations.html) of the DR3 documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I tested the equation on the entries having $G$, $V$, $G_{BP}$, and $G_{RP}$. I got 164 entries with a deviation < 0.1m; 60 entries <0.5m; 15 entries <1m; 9 entries > 1m deviation.

Answer (score 2):

To convert from G to V magnitude, use the following formula:
$$G-V=-0.0176 -0.00686(G_{bp}-G_{rp})-0.1732(G_{bp}-G_{rp})^2$$

From [Table 5.8](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GDR2/Data_processing/chap_cu5pho/sec_cu5pho_calibr/ssec_cu5pho_PhotTransf.html#Ch5.T8) of the Gaia DR2 data release documentation.

Comment: Please add some context to your answer including defining the variables used and if possible a reference for the source of this expression.  Please also consider formatting you equation with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm Guessing $ Gbp $ and $ Grp $ should really be $ G_{bp} $ and $ G_{rp} $ ?