# How do you convert from the Gaia photometric system to Johnson-Cousin?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry

I have Gaia photometry (G, G_bp, and G_rp) and need to convert it to the Johnson Cousin system. In the Data release 3 (DR3) documentation they provide tables of how to do this but I’m very confused by it and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Can you add what you've tried so far and/or exactly why you are confused? Can you also add a link to the documentation where "they provide tables of how to do this"?  Right now "I’m very confused by it and any help would be appreciated." is not an answerable question, you're asking folks to guess where you're having trouble without sharing any information abou why you're having trouble. *Thanks!*

Comment: Perhaps you can benefit from this discussion? [enter link description here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48492/how-can-i-convert-a-gaia-magnitude-g-to-johnson-v)